# Update row in MySQL with new data from select list PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to PHP (this is my first project) everyone at stackoverflow has been a tremendous amount of help.

What I am trying to do is update the status of a lead in mysql when the submit button is pressed. I currently have been able to get the select field to display what is currently in the database. Now when the user presses submit I need it to write that data back to that lead id. Below is the code I have so far.

```
    <select name="updatestatus" id="updatestatus">
    <option value="New" <?php if ($lead->status == "New") echo "selected"; ?> >New</option>
                <option value="In Process" <?php if ($lead->status == "In Process") echo "selected"; ?> >In Process</option>
                <option value="Dead" <?php if ($lead->status == "Dead") echo "selected"; ?> >Dead</option>              
            </select>
```

and:

```
    $valuesstatus["status"] = MySQL::SQLValue($updatestatus, MySQL::SQLVALUE_TEXT);
    $where["id"] =  MySQL::SQLValue($cid, MySQL::SQLVALUE_TEXT);    
    $db->UpdateRows(TABLE_LEADS, $valuesstatus, $where);
```

now if I change the `$updatestatus` to something static like "New" then it post to the data base no problem. Right now with the `$updatesstatus` variable I am getting `NULL` in the db.

Any suggestions you guys have would be appreciated!

Comment: are you sure its posting the data? you left out the part where you import your POST variables.

Comment: yes it is further up. There are several other things that get posted as well. They are all working fine.

if($_POST['submit'])
{

Comment: is there a way you can dump the compiled SQL your `$db` object is going to execute? Its probably an issue with the parameter conversion or query construction if your POST value is coming through ok.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what you are asking.. Would you like me to post the entire $_POST?

Comment: This is the error I get when I hit Submit:

Notice: Undefined variable: updatestatus in /var/www/html/sugar/support/showlead.php on line 55

Comment: I got this resolved by adding the following:

$updatestatus = mysql_escape_string(filter_var($_POST["updatestatus"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got this resolved by adding the following:

```
$updatestatus = mysql_escape_string(filter_var($_POST["updatestatus"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
```